# Jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I want to activate jQuery auto-complete in a text-box when user enters any particular character like @. means when user enters his email address like **john@gmail.com** in text-box after typing "john" when user enters "@" in text then auto-complete should be activated, and should display the list of mail extension  ("Gmail.com," "Hotmail.com," "rediffmail.com," etc).

Comment: That's nice, good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to read out your exact question/problem, but maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
var mailProviders = {
  '@gmail.com': 'Google Mail',
  '@hotmail.com': 'Windows Live Mail',
  '@blizzard.com': 'OMG GIEF GOLD!1'
};

$("#inputfield").change(function(){
  provider = String($(this).val()).split('@');
  if (provider.length == 2)
    $("#infospan").html( mailProviders[provider[1]] );
  else
    $("#infospan").html( '' );
});
```

That will update the content of `<span id="infospan"></span>` whenever the user has entered a known mail host from the list.

Answer (score 0):

[This jQuery autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) is pretty great.

I don’t think it has the exact functionality you’re looking for though (i.e. “when user enters his email address like john@gmail.com in text-box after typing "john" when user enters "@" in text then auto-complete should be activated”). You’ll need to customise it yourself for that.